# Spring Boot 2 with Java 11, HTTPS and HTTP 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, https, http2

I have a Spring Boot 2 (2.1.2) application and using the built in Tomcat. I just want to enable HTTP2 using the configuration file entry:

```
server.http2.enabled=true
```

We also switched to OpenJDK 11. We use a Let's Encrypt certificate.

Everything is working fine if port is not configured and so our app is starting on port 8080. Our app works nicely with HTTP2 and HTTPS.
If I change the port to the default https port 443 then the app starts and it listens on port 443:

```
netstat -lnp | grep 3352
tcp6       0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443      :::*                    LISTEN      3352/java
```

However if I try to access the site I got an SSL error (Secure Connection Failed).

With Java 1.8 it was working fine with port 443. (Of course the HTTP2 was not working in this case.)

Any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 11 there maybe a possibility of an issue with certs, needs -keyalg flag with keytool to generate certificates, otherwise, the key will be ciphered with the old default DSA, that is not allowed anymore with TLS1.3. With RSA it works.

Since Java 11, TLS1.3 is the new default encryption scheme for SSL sockets in JSSE, when it can be negotiated.
DSA is not supported anymore in TLS1.3